# High vote count of accepted answers hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, vote-count

After seeing the number of non-wiki upvotes I got I got curious and looked at the number of votes and answers of someone else. I ended up at [this list of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a18936%20%5Bregex%5D) and noticed I could hardly read the number of votes of answers with a high vote count:

[image: illegible vote count number]

I know that that vote count is insane, but should me make it that hard to read?

Of course the problem is due to CSS inheritance: when the number gets too high (>99?), it is wrapped inside a `span` to decrease text size:

```
<div class="vote">
  <div class="votes answered-accepted">
    <span class="vote-count-post">
      <strong>
        <span style="font-size:80%;">4042</span>
      </strong>
    </span>
    <div class="viewcount">votes</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but, as it turned out, there already was a rule for `span`s inside `.vote`:

```
.vote span {
  color: #808185;   /* aha */
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Of course this is used somewhere else, so bluntly removing that `color` style probably won't suffice.

Comment: Will this answer reach 10k upvotes by the end of 2011?

Comment: @Kenny: you meant 'question'? ;-) I think so, as there must be a way to test this issue.

Comment: No I meant bobince's RegEx answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of a recent search page/engine overhaul, the styling here was completely re-worked to match other areas of the site that show both questions and answers (suggested edits for example).

Styling glitches like the one in this question were fixed as part of that, the example in the question now looks like:

[image]